# Mithril: cannot m.redraw with m.render

Tags: mithril.js

I have an app where I want to control when to redraw the view.

I can make it work using `m.mount` and `m.redraw`:

```js
var count = 0;

var Counter = {
    view: function() {
        return m('main', [
            m('h1', ('Count: ' + count))
        ])
    }
}

m.mount(document.body, Counter);

window.setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    m.redraw();
}, 200);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril/mithril.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But if i use `m.render` (because I don't need mithril to autoredraw) it no longer works:

```js
var count = 0;

var Counter = {
    view: function() {
        return m('main', [
            m('h1', ('Count: ' + count))
        ])
    }
}

m.render(document.body, m(Counter)); // <-- The only changed line

window.setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    m.redraw();
}, 200);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril/mithril.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make mithril redraw when using `m.render` instead of `m.mount`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [here](https://mithril.js.org/redraw.html#how-it-works) in the mithril docs:

> Note that `m.redraw` only works if you used `m.mount` or `m.route`. If you rendered via `m.render`, you should use `m.render` to redraw.

```js
var count = 0;

var Counter = {
    view: function() {
        return m('main', [
            m('h1', ('Count: ' + count))
        ])
    }
}

m.render(document.body, m(Counter));

window.setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    m.render(document.body, m(Counter)); // <-- Use m.render here, not m.redraw
}, 200);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril/mithril.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```