# Does mithril.js use DOM-diffing when you use m.render?

Tags: mithril.js

In my previous [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46215562/2054731), I found that you don't use `m.redraw` with `m.render`, which makes sense, but:

- Does this mean that mithril maintains *no* relationship between rendered virtual nodes and the DOM-node they are inserted into (when using `m.render`)?
- Or does mithril *still* keep track of what is/was mounted at which node (when using `m.render`), allowing it to diff the virtual DOM and keep up the performance?

In the former case, `m.mount` might actually be faster than `m.render`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mithril will still track what has been mounted to DOM nodes, and it will do vdom diffing for multiple calls to `m.render()`.

[Docs on this feature](https://mithril.js.org/render.html#how-it-works)